# Is multiple include?() arguments in ruby possible?

Tags: ruby, include

```
def coffee_drink?(drink_list)
  drink_list.include?("coffee") ? true : drink_list.include?("espresso") ? true : false
end
```

I am learning Ruby with TOP and am looking to check for more than a single argument with the include function. I don't think my solution is too bad but surely there is a better solution I am just unable to find.

e.g. `include?("ABC", "CBA) and include?("ABC" || "CBA") wont work.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def coffee_drink?(drink_list)
  %w(coffee espresso).any? { |drink| drink_list.include?(drink) } 
end
```

or

```
def coffee_drink?(drink_list)
  (%w(coffee espresso) & drink_list).any?
end
```

note that your version could be rewritten like this

```
def coffee_drink?(drink_list)
  drink_list.include?("coffee") || drink_list.include?("espresso")
end
```